# Peewee - query ['str' in item]

Tags: python, flask, peewee

I know I'm doing this the wrong way - how do I do this without a list comprehension but with a query in peewee.  I would like to get a query to see if a search term is "in" the objects parameter.

```
knights = Knight.select()
knights = [knight for knights in knights if request.args.get('ni').lower() in \
knights.who_say.lower() ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#column-lookups

A real example might be better I'm not clear what you're trying to do exactly....but it looks like you want the case insensitive 'like'.

```
ni = request.args.get('ni')
Knights.select().where(Knights.who_say ** ni.join(('%', '%')))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I figured it out a little before you answered. knights = Knight.select().where(Knights.who say ** ('%%%s%%' % (search_term)))